# Element isn't moving smoothly

Tags: javascript, setinterval, pacman

I'm learning JavaScript for only 4 days now and I want to create Pac-Man :D.

Now my Pac-Man (currently it's just a button) should move 2 pixels every 100ms but it only moves 20 pixels in 1 second.

In my script are two `setInterval()` nested. Perhaps this is the problem

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Anyway here's my code:

````
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Pac Man</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <style>
            #pacman {
                margin: 10px;
                top: 0;
                position: absolute;
            }
            td {
                background-color: green;
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
            }
            table {
                border-spacing: 0;
                margin: 200px;
            }
            td.wall {
                background-color: darkgreen;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            walls = document.querySelectorAll(".wall");
            positionX = 10;
            positionY = 10;
            movingX = 0;
            movingY = 0;

            document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 87) { // W
                    movingX = 0;
                    movingY = -2;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 83) { // S
                    movingX = 0;
                    movingY = 2;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 65) { // A
                    movingX = -2;
                    movingY = 0;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 68) { // D
                    movingX = 2;
                    movingY = 0;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 27) { // ESCAPE
                    movingX = 0;
                    movingY = 0;
                }
            });
            
            

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="wall">

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td class="wall">

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td class="wall">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button id="pacman">Top</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        let walls = document.querySelectorAll(".wall");

        setInterval(function() {
            checkAndMove();
        }, 1000);

        function checkAndMove() {
            if (checkWalls() == 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        move();
                    }, 100);
                }
            }
        }
        function checkWalls() {
            for (i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
                rect = walls[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                if ((positionX + (movingX * 30)) > rect.left &&
                    (positionX + (movingX * 30)) < rect.right &&
                    (positionY + (movingY * 30)) > rect.top &&
                    (positionY + (movingY * 30)) < rect.bottom) {

                    return false;
                }
            }
            return 1;
        }
        function move() {
            document.getElementById("pacman").style.marginTop = (positionY += movingY) + "px";
            document.getElementById("pacman").style.marginLeft = (positionX += movingX) + "px";
        }
        
    </script>
</html>```
````

Comment: If you want to perform precisely-timed animations, you should be using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of relying on `setTimeout`. The documentation has an example on how to interpolate values using RAF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `100 * i` in `checkAndMove`.

By adding `100 * i` the `setTimeout` will be set at 100ms intervals: 0ms, 100ms, 200ms, 300ms, 400ms, 500ms, 600ms, 700ms, 800ms, and 900ms.

```js
function checkAndMove() {
  if (checkWalls() == 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        move();
      }, 100 * i); // 100 * i added here
    }
  }
}
```

I would however recommend to take `setTimeout` outside of `setInterval`. You could have one `setInterval` that runs every `100ms` which also runs `move()`. There's more advanced ways of doing this but if you're experimenting I'm sure this is sufficient for now.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Of course it will run the whole for-loop all at once. 